# How can I resolve this: 12/30/2017 is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write an SQL that calculates the total revenue from 1/2/2017 to 12/30/2017, but it does not recognise the second date. It says invalid position.

```
SELECT SUM(orderRevenue)
  AS "Total Revenue for 2017"
FROM transactionid
WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN DATE '1/2/2017' AND DATE '12/30/2017';
```

Comment: Just get rid of `DATE` in both places

Comment: take note of the date format too -`YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the correct date format -

```
SELECT SUM(orderRevenue) AS `Total Revenue for 2017`
FROM transactionid
WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN '2017-01-02' AND '2017-12-30';
```